# OpenGL geometry shader. Choose line_strip or triangle_strip

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am working with this GLSL geometry shader:

```
    #version 330 core
    layout(points) in;
    layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 128) out;
```

This mean the main C++ program is feeding the GPU with vertex which should be interpreted as points (not lines or triangles) and the geometry shader should generate triangles for each point.

What i want to do sometimes is to generate lines instead of triangles.

I replaced triangle_strip by line_strip. It works fine in both cases. What i want to do is to put a "parameter" in order to choose from main program if i want to generate lines or triangles in the geometry shader.

Actually i have duplicated my geometry shader and i have created 2 GLSL programs. Is there a best way to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Cant you use simple uniform variable to set as flag from application side ?

Comment: it is not possible to drive layout(....) directive from an uniform variable

Comment: I think then best choice you have is to maintain two shader program objects attaching different geometry shaders and check on application side if its line or triangle and enable appropriate shader program object;